# Proof $\lim n^{1/n} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis

So this is part of the text book answer(Kenneth Ross elementary analysis), and I am having difficulty with the binomial inequality

> c) Let $s_n = n^{1/n}-1$ and note $s_n \geq 0$ for all $n$.
>
> It suffices to show $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = 0$. Since $1 + s_n = n^{1/n}$, we have $n = (1+s_n)^n$ . For $n \geq 2$ we use the binomial expansion

It says for $n\geq 2$

$$n = (1+s_n)^n \geq  1+ns_n +\frac12 n(n-1)s_n^2$$

Where are these extra $n$ terms coming from in the binomial expansion?

Comment: Do you mean $$n = (1+s_n)^n \geq  1+ns_n +\frac12 n(n-1)s_n^2?$$

Comment: Do you know what 1/2 n(n-1) is?  It is a very conspicuous quantity, and is probably a clue...

Comment: Yes the formulae was off. I just corrected it it. I can see the term in-front of sn^2 is meaningful but for some reason I can’t find the exact trick that went into making that.

Comment: $Lim_{n→∞}\frac{1}{n}=0$ so $Lim_{n→∞}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ so $Lim _{n→∞}S_n=1-1=0$

Comment: @sirous $\infty^0$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: Thank you all for the input and feedback. My memory of binomial expansion is very poor and I should have easily picked this up. I will definitely be revisiting that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Where are these extra n terms coming from in the binomial expansion"

The binomial expansion of $(1 + s_n)^n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}s_n^k$

And ${n\choose 0}s_n^0 = 1$.

And ${n\choose 1}s_n^1 = ns_n$.

And ${n\choose 2}s_n^2 = \frac 12n(n-1)s_n^2$

And for $k \ge 3$,  ${n\choose k}s_n^k > 0$.

So $(1+s_n)^n = 1+ns_n+\frac 12n(n-1)s_n^2+\sum_{k=3}^n{n\choose k}s_n^k \ge 1+ns_n+\frac 12n(n-1)s_n^2$.

That's all.

Comment: Ahhh I see. wow I just realized that I remember very little from classes where we dealt with the binomial expansions. I think I must revisit it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A simpler (non-original)
proof using Bernoulli's inequality
$(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$.

$(1+1/\sqrt{n})^n \ge 1+\sqrt{n} >\sqrt{n}$.

Raising to the $2/n$ power,
$n^{1/n} < (1+1/\sqrt{n})^2
\le 1+3/\sqrt{n}
\to 1$.